# find a pattern and replace one character of it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

Will this be possible in sed ?

I want to replace , in  tuple start with [ and end with ] to |

```
"platform": "iPhone","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"},"screen_flow":["Main","Login"]
"platform": "android","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"}
```

output :

```
"platform": "iPhone","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"},"screen_flow":["Main"|"Login"]
"platform": "android","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"}
```

If not possible any other solution will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the array always in the last value, or can there be several arrays?

Comment: there can be several arrays in middle too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below perl code would replace all the `,` present inside `[]` braces with `|` symbol.

```
$ perl -pe 's/,(?=[^\[\]]*\])/|/g' file
"platform": "iPhone","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"},"screen_flow":["Main"|"Login"]
"platform": "android","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"}
```

To save the changes made,

```
perl -i -pe 's/,(?=[^\[\]]*\])/|/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk -F"[][]" 'NF>1 {gsub(/,/,"*",$2);$2="["$2"]";sub(/ \[/,"[")}1' file
"platform": "iPhone","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"},"screen_flow":["Main"*"Login"]
"platform": "android","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed ':a
s/\(\[[^][]*\),\([^][]*]\)/\1|\2/
t a' YourFile
```

posix version (so `--posix` with gnu sed)
take into accound more than a simple couple between [] and several [] on same line. Need for this e recursif call to change each single occurence one by one until there are no more case.

Comment: no back reference like in perl but there are a kind of if/goto that could do the trick with recursive call. Sed have some a logical view of litteral object that is sometime a bite "coming from mars" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

my sed solution:

```
$ sed 's/[[]\(.\+\),\(.\+\)[]]/[\1|\2]/g' file
"platform": "iPhone","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"},"screen_flow":["Main"|"Login"]
"platform": "android","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"}
```

Comment: work for sample request, but limited to 1 [] and max 2 field in []. According that, it's fine

Answer (score 0):

The next perl:

```
perl -pE 's/\[(.*?),(.*?)\]/[\1|\2]/g' <<EOF
"platform": "iPhone","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"},"screen_flow":["Main","Login"]
"platform": "android","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"}
EOF
```

prints:

```
"platform": "iPhone","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"},"screen_flow":["Main"|"Login"]
"platform": "android","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"}
```

Comment: it won't work if the input contains `["Main",,"Login"]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, sure ;) it is possible to construct many variations, when it will not works.. E.g. for example, when the last `]` missing and so on.. :) or when the comma is missing ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is just yet another instance of the issue discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25350541/1745001.

This should do it:

```
$ awk -F'[][]' -v OFS= 'gsub(/,/,"|",$2){$2="["$2"]"}1' file
"platform": "iPhone","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"},"screen_flow":["Main"|"Login"]
"platform": "android","report_attrs": {"SKU": "XYZ123","Unit Price": "32.25","Qty": "3"}
```